# Proving that if intersection of any finite no. of compact sets is non empty, then intersection of any collection of compact sets is non empty.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**To prove:** 
*If intersection of any finite no. of compact subsets of a metric space is non empty, then intersection of any collection of compact sets is non empty.*

**Proof:**
Let $A$ be an index set. Let $\{S_a\}$ (for all $a\in A)$ be a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$. 
Suppose on the contrary that the result is false and hence $\underset{a\in A}\cap S_a$ is empty. 
Let $S\in \{S_a\}$ and hence $S\not \subseteq \underset{a\in A}\cap S_a\implies S \subset \underset{a\in A}\cup S_a^c\implies \underset{a\in A}\cup S_a^c $ is an open cover for $S$. [As ${S_{a}^c}$ are open subsets of $X$]. 
Since $S$ is compact, there exist finite no. of indices $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n\in A$ such that: 
$S\subset S_{a_1}^c\cup S_{a_2}^c\cup\cdots \cup S_{a_n}^c\implies S\not\subset (S_{a_1}^c\cup S_{a_2}^c\cup\cdots \cup S_{a_n}^c)^c =\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^{i=n}S_{a_i}$ 
$S\cap \big(\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^{i=n}S_{a_i}\big)=\phi$, which is a contradiction as intersection of finite no. of collection of compact subset is non empty. 
Hence Proved.

1. Is the above proof correct?
2. I have used index set $A$. Can it be an uncountable set?

Comment: I am very suspicious towards the statement that you're trying to prove here. It is true but almost vacuously and the reason has very little to do with compactness. Any $1$-element set (a single point) is compact, but if your metric space has at least two points, there will be two (singleton) compact subspaces with empty intersection. Thus, the premise is almost never satisfied - except in very trivial cases.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Compactness is important here. One example is: Consider $E_n=(0,1/n)\subset \mathbb R$, then clearly $E_{n+1}\subset E_n$ for all $n=\{1,2,3,\cdots \}$. However, $\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$ is empty.

Comment: I have to ask you to read my comment more carefully. Can you find *any* example of a metric space with more than $1$  element such that the intersection of an arbitrary finite family of compact subsets is nonempty?

Comment: A similarly sounding (though a very different) statement: In *a compact* metric space, if any finite subfamily of a family of *closed* subsets has a nonempty intersection, then the whole family has a nonempty intersection. (This is true as it is a re-formulation of the definition of compactness in terms of closed sets, using DeMorgan's laws.)

Comment: Ohh. I understand your point now. You are right. For any metric space, if I consider some singleton subsets then their intersection will be empty.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: So "subfamily" means that it will have at least two elements? This is a theorem in Rudin's Mathematical analysis. Word "subcollection" has been used there instead of "subfamily" in your comment. Is it that "subcollection" is understood to be consisting of atleast two elements?

Comment: Subcollection of subfamily - the wording doesn't matter too much. (It depends on whether you want to call the original set of subsets a "collection" or a "family"...) In neither case it is implied that it has at least two elements, but cases with $0$ or $1$ elements are usually not very interesting.

Comment: If a collection of subsets of $M$ consists of one element $X\subseteq M$, then the intersection (i.e. set of all elements belonging to all sets of the collection) is $X$ itself. If the collection is empty, it's intersection is taken to be the whole $M$, as every element of $M$ is (vacuously) contained in *all* members of the collection (all $0$ of them!).